# Quando adiciono HTML dá erro de header

Tags: php, php-7

**página**:

```
<?php

     header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); 

?>

<html>

    <head>

        <title>Gceu IMW Muriaé - São Cristóvão </title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    </head>

    <body>

        <?php 

            require_once "../_scripts/_php/_configuracoes/erros.php";
            require_once "fpd181/PDF.php";

            $html = "<div><h1>Hoje é o dia " . date( "Y-m-d" ) . "</h1></div>";

            $pdf = new PDF();
            $pdf->AddPage();
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
            $pdf->WriteHTML($html);
            $pdf->Output();

        ?>

    </body>

</html>
```

Está dando o seguinte erro:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file in D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\wesleyanagceu.com.br\pdf\fpd181\fpdf.php:271 Stack trace: #0 D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\wesleyanagceu.com.br\pdf\fpd181\fpdf.php(1063): FPDF->Error('Some data has a...') #1 D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\wesleyanagceu.com.br\pdf\fpd181\fpdf.php(999): FPDF->_checkoutput() #2 D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\wesleyanagceu.com.br\pdf\pdf.php(29): FPDF->Output() #3 {main} thrown in D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\wesleyanagceu.com.br\pdf\fpd181\fpdf.php on line 271
```

Mas se eu retirar o `HTML` e deixar apenas o `PHP`

```
    <?php

         header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); 

    ?>

<?php 

                require_once "../_scripts/_php/_configuracoes/erros.php";
                require_once "fpd181/PDF.php";

                $html = "<div><h1>Hoje é o dia " . date( "Y-m-d" ) . "</h1></div>";

                $pdf = new PDF();
                $pdf->AddPage();
                $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
                $pdf->WriteHTML($html);
                $pdf->Output();

            ?>
```

O erro some e o `pdf` exibe. Porém com erros de acentos.

**Obs.:** Todos arquivos envolvidos são **UTF-8** sem assinatura **BOM**

Comment: Testa isso aqui troca a linha `$pdf->WriteHTML($html);`por `$pdf->WriteHTML(utf8_decode($html));`

Comment: Acho que entendi. Para gerar o pdf, é necessário usar o header de pdf. Certo? Daí o problema quando entro com outro header. Deu certo. Mas é necessário retirar o HTML de lá.  Valeu1 Mas não vai da para exibir no navegador. Só download. Queria exibir no navegador!

Answer (score 0):

Não pode haver nenhuma impressão do header para criação do PDF pela biblioteca, mesmo porquê não haveria motivo para inserir este código no meio da estrutura HTML, cria uma chamada para geração deste arquivo em outro local ou coloca seu HTML em buffer para que seja impresso após PDF.